# Leap Motion with ROS not working

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ros, leap-motion

I'm trying to implement leap motion with ROS indigo and I used the tutorials that come with the ROS leap_motion package and have set up everything as they say, however, whenever I try to execute the command line:

```
roslaunch leap_motion sensor_sender.launch
```

this shows up

```
... logging to /home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/roslaunch-JuanTelo-11993.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://JuanTelo:42806/ 

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /
    sender_freq (leap_motion/sender.py)

 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[sender_freq-1]: started with pid [12011]
[sender_freq-1] process has died [pid 12011, exit code -11, cmd /home/juantelo/catkin_ws/src/leap_motion/scripts/sender.py _freq:=0.01 __name:=sender_freq __log:=/home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/sender_freq-1.log].
log file: /home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/sender_freq-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

and it closes.

Anyone knows how I Can solve this?